# Jar file in tibco BE engine

Tags: tibco

I have a jar file .I want to include it into BE and want the output to be same as in eclipse.
How do I add this file and use the methods of it.
I tried adding it into the build path of the project folder but the methods are not coming under CUstom Functions.I am not sure if this is the correct way or not
How do i go about it.?
Help required.

Answer (score 2):

Your jar file needs to contain a file called "functions.catalog" that describes the static methods of your classes that are exposed to BE as custom functions.  The XML format for functions.catalog is described in the dev guide (Chapter 18 in BE 5.1.1's Developer's Guide).

Note that you can only expose static methods to BE.  So a "classical" library will require you to write static wrapper methods around everything that is non-static.

Comment: HI,THanks for ur reply..But I dont understand much from the description in the developers guide..I have to make an XML file inn java and add it to the jar file and den make a xsd file in Tibco BE..?Am i right.?